# require_once 'dbconnect.php'; works in five files but fails in sixth

Tags: php

I am writing ajax calls that build dropdowns and other compnonets. For each I write a php that gets the data and outputs JSON.
I simply copy and rename then change the sql, I want them to remain modular.
On the sixth it fails because the require_Once cant find the file.

Any clues?

Comment: Share the `require_once` bit from all 6 files so we can see the differences between the first 5 and the 6th.

Comment: We can't really help you unless you provide a minimal example of the problematic code as well as your file/directory structure. For all we know, your file could be nested one layer higher or lower than the others and you failed to account for it. It could even by a typo with the filename. Please provide those details so we can make an informed assessment of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies , 
I had some coffee and a break an discovered that I had somehow placed my php file in the js folder. Sooo childish, too many hours I guess.